# Manga where the main character is isekaied into a female-centered monster fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, hentai

The main character (MC) is isekaied and awakens in a fantasy world forest. He immediately gets attacked by slime girls but is rescued by an elf (rogue class - pretty sure her name is 'Vanilla Ice' in the translation).

The females in the world are turned on by the MC's pheromones which leads to sexual encounters with the elf rogue, slimes, an entire goblin gang, etc. Eventually, the MC finds a sword that is also a spirit girl who wants him to take her virginity.

Seemed like it was a newer manga or webtoon. It is not *Parallel Paradise*.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It looks like someone with a similar nickname proposed a change, which suggests that you may have accidentally logged in with a new account instead of with your existing one. If so, we can help with [merging accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harem_in_the_Labyrinth_of_Another_World

Comment: If it was you who made the proposed edit, it was that the manga was full color.

Comment: Some elements sound very like the (NSFW) webcomic Delve - the slime girl (and family), the sword which is actually a spirit etc, though the isekai elements are only revealed fairly late in the still ongoing work.  Or maybe I just don't get out much and these are standard elements in all works of this genre!

Answer (score 2):

This is *[No Man's Land](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/no-mans-land)*. It is licensed by [Lehzin](https://www.lezhinus.com/en/comic/no_man_en).

> It was on a fateful day when ordinary guy, Lee Seon-woong, found himself transported to a mysterious new world. Initially excited to make his fantasy adventure debut, his hopes are quickly dashed when he discovers he was granted no special powers or blessings. Although Seon-woong is devastated by the news that he’ll have to navigate this no man’s land without any cheat codes, he soon realizes the term “no man’s land” means something more literal around these parts, and he has something special attached to him that no other inhabitant does...

The elf is named Vanilla Ice.

[image]

The early chapters are exactly as described; the protagonist wakes up in a forest and runs into a slime.

[image]

After he experimentally touches it, it turns into a girl and eventually attacks him. He's rescued by an elf, and eventually she introduces herself as Vanilla Ice.